# Programmatic UIButton action not being called

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I've created a class that will create/manage several buttons and labels, and add them to a view, but I can't get the actions from the buttons to trigger.

Here's a simple version of the code without a 'MakerClass' that works fine (code is in the main ViewController):

```
@objc func pressed(_ sender: UIButton!) {
    print("pressed")
}
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


    let backgroundButton = UIButton()
    backgroundButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
    backgroundButton.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100)
    self.view.addSubview(backgroundButton)

    backgroundButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(pressed(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

}
```

And here is a version where I put the creation of the button into a different Class

**ViewController**

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


    MakerClass(intoView: self.view)                
}
```

**MakerClass**

```
class MakerClass {


    var backgroundButton: UIButton = UIButton()


    @objc func iwastouched(_ sender: UIButton!) {
        print("touched")
    }

    init(intoView: UIView){

        backgroundButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        backgroundButton.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 200, width: 100, height: 100)
        intoView.addSubview(backgroundButton)
        backgroundButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(iwastouched(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

    }


}
```

The project I've been using to play around with this can be downloaded from [here](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Arb96y0N7u5ijo1FDuKaGfm5MqPrcg)

I may be going about this the wrong way, as I am new to iOS programming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that as you're not retaining `MakerClass`, the target for the button is set to `NSNull()`

You can see this by adding…

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    let buttons = view.subviews as! [UIButton]
    for button in buttons {

        print(button)
        print("Target :", button.allTargets.first!)
    }
}
```

> ```
> <UIButton: 0x7ff89fd04110; frame = (0 0; 100 100); opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x60000257bac0>>
> Target : <TestProgrammaticButton.ViewController: 0x7ff89ff08050>
> <UIButton: 0x7ff89fd05020; frame = (0 200; 100 100); opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x60000257bb40>>
> Target : <null>
> ```

If you want the button to fire an action method in your view controller, you could do…

```
class MakerClass {
    init(intoView: UIView, with viewController: ViewController) {
        // configure
        backgroundButton.addTarget(viewController, action: #selector(iwastouched(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    }
}
```

But that ties your `MakerClass` to that specific `ViewController` class.

Instead, your `MakerClass` could return the formatted button and then set the target/action in the view controller.

---

*Update*

Per @RakeshaShastri's comment below, as the target is set to `NSNull()`, the app will go up the responder chain looking for an `UIResponder` (generally a `UIView` or `UIViewController`) with the correct func signature. The responder chain in your case is…

`backgroundButton` -> `ViewController.view` -> `ViewController` -> `UIWindow`

You can test this out by also adding

```
@objc func iwastouched(_ sender: UIButton!) {
    print("touched")
}
```

to your `ViewController` class.

Comment: Thanks!

Is the best way to do what I want to do this?

`init(intoView: UIView, withVC: ViewController){
        
        backgroundButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        backgroundButton.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 200, width: 100, height: 100)
        intoView.addSubview(backgroundButton)
        backgroundButton.addTarget(withVC, action: #selector(ViewController.pressed(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

    }`

Comment: That would work, but not sure it's a great solution (see my updated answer)

Comment: An interesting find, i noticed that if you had the same selector in the `ViewController`, it gets called for the code in the question. @AshleyMills can you please explain why that happens?

Comment: Ohh.. _The target object—that is, the object whose action method is called. If you specify nil, UIKit searches the responder chain for an object that responds to the specified action message and delivers the message to that object._  Ohkk... got it :|